# Sorting Tkinter TreeView column in alphabetical order

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got one problem. I've got sorting function in my treeview but it sorts not in alphabetically order. How to change code that the list will be sorted according to medicine name in my case it is te second entry widget (e1)? The code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

def add():
    tree.insert("",END,values=("",e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get()))

def sort():
    rows = [(tree.item(item,"values"), item) for item in tree.get_children('')]
    rows.sort()
    for index, (values, item) in enumerate(rows):
        tree.move(item,'',index)

e0 = Entry(root,width=15)
e0.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=1,sticky=W)
e1 = Entry(root,width=15)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(root,width=15)
e2.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
e3 = Entry(root,width=15)
e3.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)

btn1 = Button(root,text="add",width=10,command=add)
btn1.grid(row =1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,rowspan=2)
btn2 = Button(root,text="sort",width=10,command=sort)
btn2.grid(row =2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,rowspan=2)

#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)

root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the `cal1`?

Comment: upsss.... its DataEntry but cal1 has no use in this case

Comment: I got rid of it by editing the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I've change your function `add`.the `all_data` contains the text of the `e1`.
When you add a new element,it will compare the data in the `all_data` and get the index of insert.Not sure the efficiency.

The key of comparison between the capital letter and lowercase is `ascii`.You may need some changes.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

all_data = []


def add():
    index = next((index for index, item in enumerate(all_data.sort() or all_data) if e1.get().lower() <= item),(END, e1.get()))
    all_data.append(e1.get())
    tree.insert("", index, values=("", e0.get(), e1.get(), e2.get()))


e0 = Entry(root, width=15)
e0.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=1, sticky=W)
e1 = Entry(root, width=15)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(root, width=15)
e2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky=W)
e3 = Entry(root, width=15)
e3.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky=W)

btn1 = Button(root, text="add", width=10, command=add)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=2)

# treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height=25)
tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
tree.column("one", width=120)
tree.column("two", width=160)
tree.column("three", width=130)
tree.column("four", width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four", text="Data ważności")
tree["show"] = "headings"
tree.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=6, pady=20)

root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok but how to do when you add some items which start with capital letter or lower letters. Should I add to if statement another condition but how?

Comment: @Marco23 You could use `.lower()` firstly.I've edited my code.